# Call a javascript loading function and a controller action

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display a "loading" page when doing an action.

In a view I have the following form:

```
<div>
    <label class="bold center">
        Payment options
    </label>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="float-left">
            <label class="center bold">PayPal</label>
            <form id="payPal" action="@Url.Action("PaypalMethod")">
                <input type="image" name="submit"
                       src="~/Images/Functional/Icons/PayPal Pay.gif"
                       alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online." onclick="needToConfirm = false" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="float-left">
            <label class="center bold">Credit Cards</label>
            <form id="credit" action="@Url.Action("CreditCardMethod")">
                <input type="image" name="submit"
                       src="~/Images/Functional/Icons/Credit cards.png"
                       alt="CreditCards" onclick="needToConfirm = false"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have those javascript method available:

```
var spinnerVisible = false;

function ShowProgress() {
    if (!spinnerVisible) {
        $('div#spinner').fadeIn("fast");
        spinnerVisible = true;
    }
}
function HideProgress() {
    if (spinnerVisible) {
        var spinner = $('div#spinner');
        spinner.stop();
        spinner.fadeOut('fast');
        spinnerVisible = false;
    }
}
```

So when I click on the first form, for example, I would like to call the `ShowProgress()` method first, then the action, and lastly the `HideProgress()` after the results are in or simply load the next view.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the onsubmit attribut of form element.

```
<form onsubmit="ShowProgress()">
```

Comment: Oh! Haven't thought about that. I will try it.

Comment: Haha, thanks a lot! Say, would you happen to know how I could put a kind of layer to stop my user from clicking elsewhere while the loading is shown?

Comment: You can do it with just styling your spinner div like a css overlay div.

Comment: I do not know how to do that.

Comment: You can find many way to do it in css, like : 
#overlay {
 z-index:1000;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 background:#000;
 opacity:0.45;
 -moz-opacity:0.45;
 filter:alpha(opacity=45);
 visibility:hidden;
 }